# How to prove that the language L={w1#w2#. . .#wk: k ≥ 2, each wi ∈ {0,1}^* , and wi = wj for some i !=j} is not context free using the pumping lemma?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I am having trouble choosing the string to use for the proof. I know that I have to choose a string such that at least two substrings separated by the # are equal to each other but am unsure of how to approach this. If someone could please help me with this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, try $w=0^p1^p\#0^p1^p$.

Comment: After looking at it again, I am confused on what exactly the contradiction I should be trying to make is. It is not clear to me what I am trying to show such that the language is not context free.

Comment: @binarycoffee356: The pumping lemma says that if $L$ were context-free, we could decompose $w=uvxyz$ in such a way that $|vxy|\le p$, $|vy|>0$, and $uv^kxy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. You get a contradiction by showing that no matter how you decompose this $w$ as $uvxyz$ with $|vxy|\le p$ and $|vy|>0$, there is some $k\ge 0$ such that $uv^kxy^kz$ is **not** in $L$.

Comment: I knew that but in other examples, for example if I was tasked with showing the language: 0^n 1^n 2^n such that n is greater than or equal to 0 is not context free, I would find the contradiction when I pump an i such that the 0's, 1's and 2's are not equal because it would no longer be in the language, but with this problem here, I am not sure when I would find the contradiction. I am not seeing what I am trying to show such that the string is no longer in the language.

Comment: @binarycoffee356: If $vxy$ lies entirely on one side of the separator, or if the separator is in $x$, you can pump so that $w_1\ne w_2$. If the separator is in $v$ or $y$, you can pump so that the new word has no separator and therefore isn’t in $L$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That makes it all clear.

Comment: @binarycoffee356: You’re very welcome.